# How to get server variables in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Iam not a nodejs developer, but I need for a nodejs project to get the server variable for an apache authenticated user. In PHP that would be `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`, how to get it in nodejs?

Answer (score 4):

Try `process.env.ENV_VAR_NAME` to read environment variables from the host.

See the NodeJS docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)

Comment: thx, but what is the var name for the apache authentication then?

Answer (score 2):

```
process.env.ENV_VARIABLE
```

Where `ENV_VARIABLE` is the name of the variable you wish to access.

See [Node.js docs for `process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env).

Comment: thx, but what is the var name for the apache authentication then?

Answer (score 0):

This works for some server variables like REMOTE_USER, I'm still having problems with this as it doesn't work for server variables set by at least one particular module.

```
ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:3000/"
RequestHeader set X-Remote-User %{REMOTE_USER}s
```

```
const app = express();
app.get((req, res) => {
    for (let k in req.headers) {
        res.write(`${k}: ${req.headers[k]}\n`);
    }
});
```